# open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory - on Rpi4

Tags: display, raspbian-buster

RPi4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

I'm working with a portrait-mode monitor on HDMI-0 port.
No problem until this morning when I rebooted the machine.
Now the display is not able to rotate as before, only landscape with correct resolution.
The Screen Layout Editor app only enables normal orientation.

In the /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
...
[ 7.400] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms  
[ 7.400] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev  
[ 7.407] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting  
[ 7.407] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory  
[ 7.407] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
...
```

The /dev/dri folder is missing ...

With other Raspberry board (with different SD) the folder is there ..

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/dri/
by-path  card0  card1  renderD128
```

If I bring the original SD on the working RPi, it has the same problem.
So I suspect the OS ..
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do and I suspect no one else has

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'd like to set the portrait mode but I'm not able to.

Comment: But first of all, I need to solve the problem of the /dev/dri/ missing .. it halts, among other things, the touchscreen detection - I have no touch !

Answer (score 4):

With `ls -l /dev/dri` you would be able to see the major and minor ID of the devices, on the boards that have them.

Here, RPi4 with 5.10.52-v8+, it is:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,   0 25. Jul 11:25 card0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,   1 25. Jul 11:25 card1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root video 226, 128 25. Jul 11:25 renderD128
```

On the board that doesn't, you could then mknod card0 manually.  This should be done by udev or eudev, but apparently isn't.

The reason is probably because the DRI driver is not loaded or is not the right version.

See if `lsmod | grep vc4` outputs anything.  If not, modprobe vc4.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to edit your config.txt, probably /boot/config.txt, to include `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`.  (I tried vc4-kms-v3d-pi4, but that did not work for me.)  I also have `disable_fw_kms_setup=1` set, but I don't know if it's necessary.

If modprobe vc4 does work, you should add it to /etc/modules so it gets loaded on boot.

Comment: Thank you! `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` instead of the default `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` in `/boot/config.txt` on Raspbian Bullseye worked for me today.